cmake target_include_directories not working for header files
CMakeLists.txt
The following is the file content.
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    tomlplusplus
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/marzer/tomlplusplus.git
    GIT_TAG v3.4.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(tomlplusplus)

set(TOML_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "TOML_INCLUDE_DIR")
message(STATUS "TOML_SOURCE_DIR: ${TOML_INCLUDE_DIR}")
add_library(t_toml STATIC)
target_sources(t_toml
    PRIVATE
    ${TOML_INCLUDE_DIR}/toml.cpp
    PUBLIC
    ${TOML_INCLUDE_DIR}/toml.h
)

message(STATUS "DEPENDENCIES: (TOML++,${tomlplusplus_SOURCE_DIR}/include)")
target_include_directories(t_toml PUBLIC ${tomlplusplus_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

message(STATUS "DEPENDENCIES: (TOML,${TOML_INCLUDE_DIR})")
target_include_directories(t_toml PUBLIC ${TOML_INCLUDE_DIR})

toml.h
The following is the file content.
#pragma once
#ifndef _T_TOML_H_
#define _T_TOML_H_
#define TOML_EXCEPTIONS 0
#include <toml++/toml.h>

using std::string;
class TomlConfig {
public:
  TomlConfig();
  ~TomlConfig();

private:
  toml::table data;
};
#endif // 

toml.cpp
The following is the file content.
#include <toml.h>
#include <toml++/toml.h>

TomlConfig::TomlConfig() {
}
TomlConfig::~TomlConfig() {
}

error this
[proc] 执行命令: /usr/bin/cmake --build {path}/cpp/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [2/4  25% :: 0.019] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/t.dir/t.cpp.o
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/t.dir/t.cpp.o 
[build] /usr/bin/clang++  -I{path}/cpp/toml -g -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/t.dir/t.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/t.dir/t.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/t.dir/t.cpp.o -c {path}/cpp/t.cpp
[build] In file included from {path}/cpp/t.cpp:1:
[build] {path}/cpp/toml/toml.h:5:10: fatal error: 'toml++/toml.h' file not found
[build]     5 | #include <toml++/toml.h>
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] 1 error generated.

CMakeLists.txt file in the parent directory
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_subdirectory(toml)
add_executable(t t.cpp)
target_link_libraries(t toml)
target_include_directories(t PUBLIC ${TOML_INCLUDE_DIR})

They are in the same folder. I think it may be that the header file does not depend on toml++, but I don’t know how to fix it.

In your CMakeLists.txt you specify include directories for the target t_toml. The error message is about target t. You didn't add include directories for that target.

@Tsyvarev I add the CMakeLists.txt file in the parent directory, I think using public in target_include_directories should be visible to all targets that depend on it.

It's okay, it was a spelling mistake

Your create a target t_toml, but link with toml: target_link_libraries(t toml).
